# Implemented method in RecyclerViewAdapter does not call

Tags: android, interface, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView Adapter Class As:

```
public class AdapterForRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> implements SuccessInterface{

Context context;
JSONArray sJsonArray;

private SuccessInterface sAdapterInterface;

public AdapterForRecyclerViewContext context, JSONArray expressJsonObject) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sJsonArray= expressJsonObject;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_list_parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder (view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = sJsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        String restaurantNameString = jsonObject.getString("restaurant_name");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("Error in:", "Dine Exp Adapter");
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sJsonArray.length();
}
//This is the method that I want to execute from Fragment

@Override
public void onSubmittedSuccessfully(int i) {
    try {
        Log.d("Reply update Adapter", String.valueOf(i));
        JSONObject abc = sJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray jsonArrayObject = abc.getJSONArray("replies");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("review", "submit");
        jsonArrayObject.put(jsonObject);
        abc.put("replies", jsonArrayObject);
        sJsonArray.put(i,abc);
        Log.d("Reply updat obj", sJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("Reply Update", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public LinearLayout itemLinearLayout, restaurantLinearLayout, checkinLinearLayout, newRestaurantLinearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_item_layout_card_list_dine_express_fragment);
        restaurantLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_restaurant_layout_card_list_dine_express_fragment);
        checkinLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_checkin_layout_card_list_dine_express_fragment);
        newRestaurantLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_new_restaurant_layout_card_list_dine_express_fragment);

        newRestaurantLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        replyLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        }
    }
}

public interface ExpressAdapterInterface {
    void replyFragmentStarted(String s, int i);
}
```

}

SuccessInterface is defined in a Fragment, like:

```
public class RepliesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private ReplySubmitSuccessInterface replySubmitSuccessInterface;
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    replySubmitSuccessInterface = (ReplySubmitSuccessInterface) getContext();
    replySubmitSuccessInterface.replySubmittedSuccessfully(i);
    }
 public interface ReplySubmitSuccessInterface {
        void replySubmittedSuccessfully(int i);
    }
}
```

This method is not called in the Above Adapter where I have Implemented with the Proper Context. Is this the right approach or is there any work around?

Any Help is Appreciated!

Comment: can you elaborate your question. what exactly you want to do??

Comment: I have implemented an interface in the Adapter as you can see above. What I am unable to achieve is calling the method from the fragment. I want to update recyclerView Item at one position and to do that I am implementing the method, but it does not execute.